# Customizing sections

Tags: sectioning

How to customize the "sections" to get **Section number.~Section name** ? i.e., section number followed by the period, space and the section name.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very short solution: add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is there a way to reduce the default spacing between the period and the section name ?

Comment: The spacing in this code is `1em` (`\quad`); given as an example. Try `\enspace` (0.5em) instead, or `\hspace{xx em}` for another spacing.